# LDAP Sub Query to fetch SamAccountName from CN

Tags: java, ldap

Currently I have this query as mentioned below which returns all users but each user has a parameter called manager which returns

```
"CN=Peder Ellingsen,OU=Users,OU=NO,OU=Countries,DC=xds,DC=xxx,DC=com"
```

Need the `samAccountName` instead of the CN above, need help with LDAP Subquery which can help me to get the `samAccountName` directly by modifying the query mentioned below

Wanted to avoid double hits to LDAP server just to get the `samAccountName`.

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberof=cn=MyCompass_NO,OU=Groups,OU=Common,OU=Applications,DC=xds,DC=xxx,DC=com))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your filter is what you have written above try this

```
  (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(memberof=cn=MyCompass_NO,OU=Groups,OU=Common,OU=Applications,DC=xds,DC=xxx,DC=com))
```

This will give first parameter as SamAccountName=username

if you want only Samaccountname printed use this

```
    Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
    Attribute attr = attrs.get(sAMAccountName);
    if(attr!=null)
    {
    NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll();

    while (e.hasMore()) {
        String value = (String) e.next();
        System.out.println(value);
    }}
```

if you want to list down all the Samaccountname then use this

```
 (&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*))
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter by whatever you want, and get sAMAccountName, here is how I did in our servers:

```
ldapsearch -h host -p port -b dc=organization.com -W -D cn=admin,dc=organization.com '(&(objectclass=person)(uid=someuid))' sAMAccountName
```

the interesting part is the filter

```
'(&(objectclass=person)(uid=someuid))' sAMAccountName
```

where you filter by objectclass and uid, and get sAMAccountName attribute.